# Magento 2 security scan failed AngularJS and XS Vulnerability

Tags: magento2, security, security-scan-tool

Our Magento 2 site failed the AngularJS and XS Vulnerability checks. Does anyone know how this can be fixed.

[image]

Comment: What version of Magento you use? Update to 2.2.7 should resolve problem

Comment: It's Magento 2.2.6.

Comment: Suggest to upgrade at  `2.2.9` and   it will resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can get an answer from your share screenshot. Action tab already gives the answer what action need to resolve the issue. Asking to apply patches. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: There are no patches for the issue above. They are based on "best practices".

Comment: any  update on patch?

Comment: No patches available, you have to upgrade to 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Magento 2.3 and the issue was resolved.